# Using R to extract indices of a matching letter from a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of file names called "Face" which looks like this:

```
cK0521d07.png
ck0101a02.png
ck0221c01.png
ck0121b01.png
ck0221g08.png
ck0321c22.png
```

All I care about is the letter right after the ck and following four digits (case insensitive). For example, I want those indices where the letter is c, so what I did was:

```
grep("([:alnum:]{6})c([:digit:]{2}).png", Face)
```

I expected R to return **3 and 6** to me, but instead, it returned **integer(0)**. I must do something wrongly but I don't know what it is. Please someone tell me, that will be so helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Note for those who want to close as a typo: just fixing `album` to `alnum` is not fixing the regex.  The dot must also be escaped and anchors might need adding.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! I just corrected the typo. I am pretty sure I typed "alnum" when I was coding. BTW I solved this question by `grep(".+c.+", Face)`, an alternative way, but it is still great to know how the POSIX classes works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These POSIX character classes must reside inside `[` and `]` (bracket expressions). Use

```
"[[:alnum:]]{6}c[[:digit:]]{2}\\.png"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L0w46l/1)

Add anchors if necessary (`^` at the start and `$` at the end) to match the *entire* string.

Note that the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot, otherwise it matches any character.

```
Face <- c("cK0521d07.png","ck0101a02.png","ck0221c01.png","ck0121b01.png","ck0221g08.png","ck0321c22.png")
grep("[[:alnum:]]{6}c[[:digit:]]{2}\\.png", Face)
## => [1] 3 6
```

[R demo online](https://ideone.com/MUPgQZ)

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! Your solution works perfectly. The ":album:" was an AutoCorrect which I failed to notice when I posted the question. I have two newly generate questions though.
First, **do these POSIX classes need two pairs of brackets or the classes themselves comprise one pair of brackets?**
Also, I know that the backslash is an escape character in R, but **why doesn't the "\\." part cause an additional backslash before the literal dot?**

Comment: As I wrote, POSIX character classes like `[:punct:]` or `[:alnum:]` must be inside bracket expressions, you can write `[[:alpha:][:digit:]]` to match the same chars as `[[:alnum:]]`. `"\\."` defines a `\.` string, a literal backslash and a dot, and that pattern matches a literal dot in the input string.